# Is it possible to run a statically-linked ELF binary on Android?

Tags: android, elf, static-linking

Android is based on a Linux kernel, and as far as I know, statically linked ELF binaries require only a kernel to run. Although Android doesn't include glibc, the system call interface should still exist, being built into the kernel. I know any practical application would be *huge* when statically linked, but this is purely hypothetical. Would it work?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that what you want to do is take some static libraries on your Linux machine and link them statically with an object file of your own in an attempt to overcome their absence on Android. The problem with this is that the two machines almost certainly don't use the same CPU architectures so the libraries weren't built for Android and the machine code won't be "understood" by Android. Theoretically, you'd have to cross-compile the libraries too and link your program with that.

However Android already has a Standard C library called Bionic. It replaces glibc on Android.

Answer (score 0):

For native development on Android you typically create native **.so** libraries that need to be cross compiled for each supported architecture (`arm`, `arm64`, `mips`, `x86`, `x86_64`). These libraries can be loaded referenced by an APK using **JNI** calls.

While you could use ELF binaries (**.so** files are made with standard compiler such as gcc) you would need one for each target architecture you would want to run your app on.

Also while Android **can** load the `x86` or arm version of the **.so** files for `x86_64` & `arm64` respectively it is recommended to create all 4 versions if that is what you are supporting. The native libraries are loaded based upon folder structure.

**Example:** an `arm46` system will load the arm **.so** file out of `lib/arm` ONLY IF `lib/arm64` does not exist. The results is any libraries that include lib/arm64 will cause your app to break on `arm64` systems unless you include both an `arm` & `arm64` versions.